# Sorting a struct list in C

Tags: c

I've been trying to sort a single linked struct list using a bubble sort routine, I have managed to come up with, however, I'm getting a segmentation core dump error. Here is the part of code (Functions) responsible for sorting the list.

```
typedef struct ELEMENT {
    char name [15];
    char symbol [3];
    float weight;
    struct ELEMENT* next;
} ELEMENT;
typedef ELEMENT* LIST;

LIST create_element (LIST h){
    LIST head = malloc (sizeof (ELEMENT));
    head -> next = h;
    return (head);
}

LIST swap_head (LIST* Prev, LIST* current, LIST* Next){ //sorting head node
    ELEMENT dummy;
    dummy.next = *Next;
    //Swaping nodes and re-establishing links
    (*current) -> next = (*Next) -> next;
    (dummy.next) -> next = *current;
    
    //Updating Prev, current and Next
    *Prev = dummy.next;
    *Next = (*current) -> next;
    *current = (*Prev) -> next;
    
    return (*Prev);  // returning the new head node for safe keeping
}

void swap_node (LIST* Prev, LIST* current, LIST* Next){     // sorting nodes after the head of list
    ELEMENT dummy;
    dummy.next = *Next;
    //Swaping nodes and re-establishing links
    (*current) -> next = (*Next) -> next;
    (dummy.next) -> next = *current;
    (*Prev) -> next = dummy.next;

    //Updating Prev, current and Next
    *Prev = dummy.next;
    *Next = (*current) -> next;
    *current = (*Prev) -> next;
}

LIST sort (LIST head){
    LIST h = head;
    LIST current = h;
    LIST Prev = NULL;
    LIST Next = current -> next;
    LIST count = h;
    while (count != NULL){
        current = h;
        Prev = NULL;
        Next = current -> next;
        while ( Next != NULL){
            if (current -> weight < Next -> weight){
                if (Prev != NULL)
                    swap_node (&Prev, &current, &Next);
                else
                    h = swap_head (&Prev, &current, &Next);
            }
            else
                Prev = current;
                current = Next;
                Next = current -> next;
        }
        count = count -> next;
    }
    return (h);
}
```

When I exclude the sorting function from the entire code, the code works fine, so I'm sure this is where the issue lies. Here is the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NOELEMENTS 10

typedef struct ELEMENT {
    char name [15];
    char symbol [3];
    float weight;
    struct ELEMENT* next;
} ELEMENT;
typedef ELEMENT* LIST;

LIST create_element (LIST h){
    LIST head = malloc (sizeof (ELEMENT));
    head -> next = h;
    return (head);
}

LIST swap_head (LIST* Prev, LIST* current, LIST* Next){ //sorting head node
    ELEMENT dummy;
    dummy.next = *Next;
    //Swaping nodes and re-establishing links
    (*current) -> next = (*Next) -> next;
    (dummy.next) -> next = *current;
    
    //Updating Prev, current and Next
    *Prev = dummy.next;
    *Next = (*current) -> next;
    *current = (*Prev) -> next;
    
    return (*Prev);  // returning the new head node for safe keeping
}

void swap_node (LIST* Prev, LIST* current, LIST* Next){     // sorting nodes after the head of list
    ELEMENT dummy;
    dummy.next = *Next;
    //Swaping nodes and re-establishing links
    (*current) -> next = (*Next) -> next;
    (dummy.next) -> next = *current;
    (*Prev) -> next = dummy.next;

    //Updating Prev, current and Next
    *Prev = dummy.next;
    *Next = (*current) -> next;
    *current = (*Prev) -> next;
}

LIST sort (LIST head){
    LIST h = head;
    LIST current = h;
    LIST Prev = NULL;
    LIST Next = current -> next;
    LIST count = h;
    while (count != NULL){
        current = h;
        Prev = NULL;
        Next = current -> next;
        while ( Next != NULL){
            if (current -> weight < Next -> weight){
                if (Prev != NULL)
                    swap_node (&Prev, &current, &Next);
                else
                    h = swap_head (&Prev, &current, &Next);
            }
            else
                Prev = current;
                current = Next;
                Next = current -> next;
        }
        count = count -> next;
    }
    return (h);
}

LIST fetchELEMENTS (LIST head){
    head -> next  = NULL;
    printf ("Enter the following:\n\nElement Name\tSymbol\tAt.Weight\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NOELEMENTS; i++){
        char str [256];
        fgets (str, 256, stdin);
        sscanf (str, "%s %s %f", (head -> name), (head -> symbol), &(head -> weight));
        if (i < NOELEMENTS - 1)
            head = create_element (head);
    }
    return (head);
}

void print_out (LIST h){
    LIST head = h;
    printf ("No.\t%-12s\t\t%-12s\t\t%-12s\n", "Element Name", "Symbol", "At.Weight");
    for (int i = 0; i < NOELEMENTS; i++){
        printf ("%d\t%-12s\t\t%-12s\t\t%-f\n", i+1, head -> name, head -> symbol, head -> weight);
        if (i < NOELEMENTS - 1)
            head = head -> next;
    }
}

int main () 
{
 LIST head = malloc (sizeof (ELEMENT));
 head = fetchELEMENTS (head);
 head = sort (head);
 print_out (head);
 return (0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the segmentation code dumped error, can't believe I missed this. The output, however, is still not sorted. It was definitely changed but not sorted, any idea what's the reason ?

Comment: My suggestion is to always use braces with every conditional or loop statement.